# How to make regex accept strings with a dot

Tags: regex, perl

I'm currently debugging a Perl script and encountered some errors which will be described in the following sections below:

In the script, I have this `-td` variable designed to accept a string like `1n, 5n, 0.3n, 0.8n`

But when I try to use the the last two from the said list, the script does not work as intended, and only works fine when I use only the first two from the list.

To give you an overview, I have written some portions of the script, then after the code, I will state my concern:

```
if (scalar(@ARGV) < 1){ &get_usage() };
# Getoptions Setup ##
GetOptions (
  'h|help'          => \$help,
  'v|version'       => \$version,
  'i|input=s'       => \$input,
  'o|output=s'      => \$output,

   ...  # more options here

  'td=s'          => \$td_val, # this is the line in question
  'val=s'         => \$v_var,

   ...  # more options here

) or die get_usage();  # this will only call usage of script or help

   ...  # more codes here

get_input_arg();   # this function will validate the entries user had inputted

#assigning to a placeholder value for creating a new file
$td_char="\ttd=$td_val" if $td_val;
$td_char=" " if !$td_val;

... # fast forward ...

sub get_input_arg{

...
# here you go, there is wrong in the following regex to accept values such as 0.8n 
unless (($td_val=~/^\d+(m|u|n|p)s$/)||($td_val=~/^\d+(m|u|n|p|s)$/)||($td_val=~/^\d+$/)){#
print "\n-td error!\nEnter the required value!\n";
get_usage();

... # more functions here ...

}
```

For explanation:

1. On the console user will input `-td 5n`
2. The `5n` will be assigned to `td_val` and to `td_char` and be used for printing later
3. This `5n` will be validated by `get_input_arg()` function which will pass to the regex `unless` line.

For `5n` input, script work as intended, but when we use `-td 0.8n`, then after validating it, it will print the error message after the `unless` line on the console

I know the regex is failing on matching with regards to using `0.8n` as `td` input, but I don't know how can I fix it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$td_val =~ /^[0-9.]+[munp]s?$/`

Comment: I have try that but it didn't work

Comment: If you want to use a special character you prefix it with a \  e.g. /\d+\.\d+/

Comment: On values 0.8n and 0.5n

Comment: https://eval.in/318550 says otherwise.

Comment: @Meeyaw: Сухой27's suggestion is quite correct. You must have copied it wrongly

Comment: @Borodin: I have copied it the wrong way

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use

```
unless (($td_val=~/^\d+(\.\d+)?[munp]s$/)||($td_val=~/^\d+(\.\d+)?[munps]$/)||($td_val=~/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/))
```

Explanation:

Your regex has `\d+` which matches only integers.. so replace it with `\d+(\.\d+)?` (integral part followed by optional decimal part)

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iX2fB9/1)